# While loop overperforming for loop - Python

Tags: python, performance, loops

I'm writing a simple integration approximation function. Thing is that no matter what I do in my code, it seems that my `while` implementation always beats my `for` implementation which is very weird, since `for` should be faster as it does not check a boolean expression and increase a variable on each iteration.

The code:

```
import math
import time
import numpy as np

def function(x):
    return math.cos(x)

def integrate_while(func, x_start, x_end, n_steps=10_000):
    step_length = (x_end - x_start) / n_steps
    area = 0
    x = x_start
    x_end -= step_length
    while x < x_end:
        area += func(x) + func(x + step_length)
        x += step_length
    area *= step_length / 2
    return area

def integrate_for(func, x_start, x_end, n_steps=10_000):
    step_length = (x_end - x_start) / n_steps
    area = 0
    ls = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, n_steps)
    for x in ls:
        area += func(x) + func(x + step_length)
    area *= step_length / 2
    return area

def integrate_for_range(func, x_start, x_end, n_steps=10_000):
    step_length = (x_end - x_start) / n_steps
    area = 0
    for i in range(n_steps):
        x = x_start + i * step_length
        area += func(x) + func(x + step_length)
    area *= step_length / 2
    return area

def test():
    integrate_funcs = [integrate_while, integrate_for, integrate_for_range]
    for integrate_func in integrate_funcs:
        t1 = time.time_ns()
        result = integrate_func(function, 0, math.pi / 2, n_steps=1_000_000)
        t2 = time.time_ns()
        print(f'Function {integrate_func.__name__}. Result: {round(result, 4)}, Elapsed ns: {t2-t1:,}.')

test()
```

Results:

```
Function integrate_while. Result: 1.0, Elapsed ns: 569,587,400.
Function integrate_for. Result: 1.0, Elapsed ns: 638,829,800.
Function integrate_for_range. Result: 1.0, Elapsed ns: 596,499,300.
```

Edit: Already checked the `np.linspace` object creation impact on total excecution time of the `for` loop and it is less than 1% of total time.

Comment: Is it anything to do with `step_length`?

Comment: @quamrana It probably was a little bit different. Just edited, should be exactly the same but excecution times are the same.

Comment: It actually may be because `np.linspace` returns not the list but object that satisfies `typing.Iterable` (so it's iterable), and `for-loop` calls `next()` to iterate over iterable. And as you know function call is very heavy operation

Comment: @sudden_appearance It doesn't call `next()` and the iteration isn't where most of the time goes.

Comment: `numpy` arrays, like you're getting from `linspace()`, are optimized for doing bulk, vectorized operations.  Looping over one is *never* going to be the highest-performance option.  You can get rid of the loop completely, something like `area = np.sum(func(ls) + func(ls + step_length))` - but note that you'd have to modify the function being integrated to use `numpy` functions rather than the ones from `math`.

Comment: Could you use `{t2-t1:,}` for better readability of the numbers?

Comment: @jasonharper I tried it and using a `numpy` function increases time performance drastically. But thing is I don't know if functions will have `numpy` implementation inside.

Comment: creating np.float64 objects and iterating over numpy arrays is much more expensive than float types in list because of the way CPython (and Numpy) is/are designed. That being said, both are extremely slow compared to native code. Cython can speed up that if you do-not-use/cannot Numpy but vectorizing functions is often simpler and a rather good habit.

Comment: What time do you get for `integrate_for` if you additionally do `x = float(x)` in the loop before updating `area`?

Comment: Just added a `range` implementation so I don't iterate through a numpy array. Performance got half the way to the `while implementation.

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti - You compute an additional multiplication in the `range` for loop 1_000_000 times, that's less than 27ns per iteration.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yes, changed it to `x += step_length` with initial value of `x_start` and excecution times are roughly the same.

Comment: Still curious what you get when you additionally do `x = float(x)` as I suggested. I think despite the "extra work", it'll be *faster*.

Comment: Typically, most of the time is spent converting `numpy` types to `python` types. Check the execution time for `ls = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, n_steps).tolist()` in your `np.linspace` loop implementation.

Comment: @KellyBundy Already outperformed while with previous mentioned changes. Added area = floa(0) and x = float(x_start) before the for loop and gained like 10% extra performance.

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti To be clear, I wasn't trying to make it faster (since I think that's not what the question is about), I was trying to point out that you're using NumPy floats and operations with them are slower than with Python floats (so much so that it more than compensates for the extra conversion). If this question were about making it faster, I'd have two other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Original `np.linspace` was the problem since `numpy` arrays are not thought to be iterated as there is important overhead when you do so.

After changing `np.linspace` with native `range` type, I could overperform the simple `while` loop.

Also some extra changes improved performance too:

- Setting variable types before entering into for loop (10% less time).
- Change loop logic to avoid extra function calls (50% less time).

Final function code:

```
def integrate_for_range_opt(func, x_start, x_end, n_steps=10_000):
    step_length = (x_end - x_start) / n_steps
    area = 0.0
    x = float(x_start) + step_length
    for i in range(n_steps - 1):
        area = area + func(x)
        x = x + step_length
    area = area * 2.0 + func(x_start) + func(x_end)
    return area * step_length / 2.0
```

Comment: I answered it in the first sentence, probably misphrased as an Answer, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I rephrased my comment already. You do mention some possible reasons, but there's no demonstration of it. And since the 10% statement is wrong, one might doubt the other statements as well, that's why proper demonstrations would've been good.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't actually ask a question and to me it seemed to ask for an explanation, but your comments and your own answer give me the impression that what you really want is a fast solution. So here's a faster one, making Python functions do more work for you:

```
from itertools import accumulate, repeat

def integrate_map_accumulate(func, x_start, x_end, n_steps=10_000):
    step_length = (x_end - x_start) / n_steps
    xs = accumulate(repeat(step_length, n_steps - 2),
                    initial = x_start + step_length)
    area = sum(map(func, xs))
    area = area * 2.0 + func(x_start) + func(x_end)
    return area * step_length / 2.0
```

In my testing with your benchmark code, that reduced the time from ~0.21 seconds (for your answer's solution) to ~0.14 seconds.